# IE: Object expected in most .live binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I write application in PHP with some AJAX. I have problem only with IE (tested on 8.0.6001.18702). FF, Chrome Opera work great.

I get **Error: Object expected** error on line *`edytuj_news(`*

HTML:

```
<div id="news">
    <a href="#1">edit</a>
    <a href="#2">edit</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#news a')
    .live('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        edytuj_news(
            $(this).attr('hash').slice(1)
        );
    });

});

function edytuj_news(idNews){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/ajax/get_news',
       data: {"idNews": idNews},
       cache: false,
       timeout: 3000, 
       success: function(json){
           var data = $.parseJSON(json);
        // ... work
       } 
   });
}
```

All my click function act like that.

OK. I find bug. I don't give You chance.
I programing in Netbeans i I use @todo marks. Of course commented. But IE don't see //.

Comment: should $(this).attr('hash').slice(1) not be 'href' ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have an element on your page whose "id" is exactly the same as that function name?

Comment: no, i want hash. Without leading #

Comment: There no other edytuj_news or idNews

Comment: The thing is, @karion, the ".attr()" function is for getting **attributes** of elements. There's no "hash" attribute on your `<a>` tag, but there is an "href" value.

Comment: when i insert id or get it through var i got same problem. So it`s not that.

Comment: @Pointy: `.attr('hash')` is very valid and works :)

Comment: @karion: By the way, are you testing this on your local machine or a live server? See -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498030/outstanding-issues-with-jquery-ajax-in-ie8

Comment: @stealthyninja: live local server so I can't link :(

Comment: @Martin Jesperson well after I typed that comment I started wondering whether it was a jQuery feature that I just didn't know about - I'm at a conference however so I didn't have time to investigate :-)  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

@karion: While it's valid JavaScript, Internet Explorer regularly fails when you've got a `},` at the end of a data array, so I suggest you update this portion of your code to remove that last comma after the closing bracket for `success` and see if that solves the issue (or gives another error):

```
   success: function(json){
       var data = $.parseJSON(json);
    // ... work
   }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem for i8, ie7 and ie6 had this problem however.